# HOG and LBP on weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka, feature-extraction, image-classification

I'm new to the subject of ML so I apologize as my questions may seem too basic.
I have an image dataset and my supervisor asked me to do feature extraction using HOG and LBP filters. So far I have been working with weka, and I couldn't fine any useful tutorials on how to implement these filters on weka, is it possible? and if not, how else can implement these filters to extract features from my dataset?

Answer (score 0):

**Weka**

You could use and/or extend the [imageFilter](https://github.com/mmayo888/ImageFilter) Weka package. It uses LIRE under the hood, which has a range of feature extraction methods implemented.

**ADAMS**

If you don't mind using another framework, then you could make use of the plugins for LIRE in [ADAMS](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/). Its *adams-imaging* module also offers support for a range of LIRE feature generators ([download](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/download/snapshot/) either the *adams-annotator* or *adams-base-all* snapshot).

Using its workflow engine, you can run the flow [adams-imaging-feature_generation](https://github.com/waikato-datamining/adams-base/blob/fbbadeeb2bb35a77f5e3293d9cf2aaec58501eb6/adams-imaging/src/main/flows/adams-imaging-feature_generation.flow), which generates generates PHOG and LocalBinaryPatterns features from a range of images and displays them as spreadsheet. You could use this flow as basis and turn it into one that allows you to select images interactively and then saves them as CSV or ARFF file.

Comment: I do have this package installed, but sill can't find these 2 specific filters there

Comment: [LIRE](https://github.com/dermotte/LIRE) offers PHOG (part of imageFilter) and LocalBinaryPatterns (you may have to expose that yourself in the package - hence "extend the package").

Comment: I've extended my answer to point out ADAMS, as it incorporates LIRE as well.